# How to add Tuples and apply a ceiling/clamp function in F#

Tags: f#, tuples, rgb

So I am working on a project using F# for some SVG line manipulations.

I thought it would be good to represent color an RGB value as a tuple (R,G,B). It just made sense to me. Well since my project involves generating SVG lines in a loop. I decided to have a color offset, conveniently also represented in a tuple (Roffset, Goffset, Boffset)

An offset in this case represents how much each line differs from the previous.

I got to a point where I needed to add the tuples. I thought since they were of the same dimensions and types, it would be fine. But apparently not. I also checked the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd233200.aspx) on tuples, but I did not find anything about how to add them or combine them.

Here is what I tried. Bear in mind I tried to omit as much irrelevant code as possible since this is a long class definition with **LOTS** of members.

```
 type lineSet ( 10+ params omitted ,count, colorOff :byte*byte*byte, color :byte*byte*byte ,strokeWid , strokeWidthOff  ) =

    member val Color = color with get, set
    member val ColorOffset = colorOff with get, set
    member val lineCount = count with get, set
    interface  DrawingInterfaces.IRepresentable_SVG with 
        member __.getSVGRepresenation() = 

          let mutable currentColor = __.Color
          for i in 1..__.lineCount do
             currentColor <- currentColor + __.ColorOffset
```

That last line of code is what I wanted to do. However, it appears you cannot add tuples directly.

I also need a way to clamp the result so it cannot go over 255, but I suspect a simple try with block will do the trick. OR I could let the params take a type int*int*int and just use an if to reset it back to 255 each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, the clamping function in your code does not actually work - you need to convert the numbers to integers before doing the addition (and then you can check if the integer is greater than 255). You can do something like this:

```
let addClamp (a:byte) (b:byte) = 
  let r = int a + int b
  if r > 255 then 255uy else byte r
```

Also, if you work with colors, then it might make sense to define a custom color type rather than passing colors around as tuples. That way, you can also define `+` on colors (with clamping) and it will make your code simpler (but still, 10 constructor arguments is a bit scary, so I'd try to think if there is a way to simplify that a bit). A color type might look like this:

```
type Color(r:byte, g:byte, b:byte) = 
  static let addClamp (a:byte) (b:byte) = 
    let r = int a + int b
    if r > 255 then 255uy else byte r
  member x.R = r
  member x.B = b
  member x.G = g
  static member (+) (c1:Color, c2:Color) = 
    Color(addClamp c1.R c2.R, addClamp c1.G c2.G,addClamp c1.B c2.B)
```

Using the type, you can then add colors pretty easily and do not have to add clamping each time you need to do that. For example:

```
Color(255uy, 0uy, 0uy) + Color(1uy, 0uy, 0uy)
```

But I still think you could make the code more readable and more composable by refactoring some of the visual properties (like stroke & color) to a separate type and then just pass that to `LineSet`. This way you won't have 10+ parameters to a constructor and your code will probably be more flexible too.

Comment: I was planning on rewriting it to use records as paramaters to make it much simpler.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a modified version of your code which I think is a bit nicer

```
let add3DbyteTuples (tuple1:byte*byte*byte , tuple2:byte*byte*byte) =
    let inline intify (a,b,c) = int a,int b,int c
    let inline tripleadd (a,b,c) (d,e,f) = a+d,b+e,c+f
    let clamp a = if a > 255 then 255 else a
    let R,G,B = tripleadd (intify tuple1) (intify tuple2)
    clamp R,clamp G,clamp B
```

Comment: Amazing, John. You have been answering and commenting a lot on my posts lately. I am quite grateful for your stunning insight. This is very efficient. I noticed you did not have to assign the result to a variable to return it. The multiple return is recognized as a tuple, something I understand, but did not think of.